# In admin panel overview "Jirafe" Service is down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am using **"Spree"** gem in rails.

In spree admin panel overview layout "Jirafe" service dashboard is not working, I got the following error.

**The Jirafe service is currently down for scheduled maintenance. Please try again later. We     apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for Spree Commerce and I'd like to apologise about this error. When we wrote the code that connects to Jirafe, we did not include safeguards against the situation where Jirafe was down. This means that when Jirafe inevitably goes down, we run into this sort of problem.

I've personally fixed this now on the 1-3-stable, 2-0-stable and master branches. I've also just done a 2.0.3 release, which removes the dashboard completely. Please upgrade to that version:

```
gem "spree", "2.0.3"
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work.  Modified my gemfile and did a bundle install.  No dice.

Comment: @Nizar: Could you please try 2.0.3 instead?

Comment: Did that. Now I don't see the Jirafe option at all.

Comment: We have removed Jirafe completely. It will be back once their service is back.

Answer (score 1):

An analytic dashboard powered by [Jirafe](http://www.jirafe.com). The dashboard is available by default in the spree from 1.0.  In spree store admin panel.

Currently the error message you are getting because these services servers are under scheduled maintenance.

You won't be able to access the admin section of your store unless jirafe servers are up.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone! I've also been getting the same error for the past few hours.

Same on my Spree Dashboard and on the [Jirafe Site Dashboard](https://en.jirafe.com/dashboard/signin) so it looks like a problem there end.

It looks like the front-end data js script is working fine...
So it's still tracking data but you wont be able to see your pretty circles until the "maintenance" is finished.